# Applying Matrix Operation Code

Tags: matrices, calculations, syntax

I'm (relatively) new to LaTeX, and I'm having a syntactic problem using the wonderful code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112683/34359), which allows arbitrary matrix operations in LaTeX.

I wrote a macro to generate certain matrices.  E.g.:

```
\def\GetRotationMatrixZ#1{
    cos(#1),-sin(#1),0,
    sin(#1), cos(#1),0,
          0,       0,1
}
```

Now I would like to use it with the linked code's \matnew, \matset commands.  Everything obvious I tried, however, failed miserably.  I tried many variations on the macro's syntax, but I'm stuck.

EDIT: the main usage case would look something like:

```
\matnew \transformMatrixA
\matset \transformMatrixA {\GetRotationMatrixY\whatever}
% . . .
\matmul \transformMatrix \transformMatrixA \transformMatrixB
```

I've tried similar things; I don't remember exactly which.  This particular example gives:

```
Unexpected comma: extra arguments ignored.
```

Comment: In what way do you want to use it with `\matnew` and `\matset`? Could you include in your post what you've tried...? Perhaps that'll make things more clear.

Comment: @Werner: I don't remember _all_ the things I've tried exactly, but I added an example of one of them.

Answer (score 4):

`LaTeX3` people will give more authoritative answers (particularly they know how to generate variants to `\matset` which will expand its argument). In the mean time, perhaps this helps (it seems the issues were that you did not use semi-colons to end rows, and there was a problem of expansion).

`TeX` is a macro language, where the key word is expansion. Even if you use higher abstraction levels like `LaTeX2` (which tries to its best to \emph{hide} from the user the programming possibilities) or `LaTeX3` (which to the contrary has a very well-thought and sophisticated scheme to make it easier to code, while at the same time clearly separating programmer tasks from end user tools), you can not escape that. It seems that the `\matset` macro from the code you linked too does not expand its argument. If you try to use it as `\matset\MatrixA {\macro{3}}`, it will receive  `\macro{3}` and not the semi-colon separated rows it seems to expect. You first need to tell `TeX` to expand `\macro{3}` to that list or rows. It would be immediate for a `\LaTeX3` programmer to generate the variant of `\matset` which first expands its argument, as a work-around, `\expandafter\matset\expandafter\MatrixA \expandafter{\macro{3}}` would do it. Notice that the brace `{` is part of the input stream and must be jumped over by `\expandafter`.

```
%% (to be embedded in the code from [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112683/34359))

\def\GetRotationMatrix #1{%
    cos(#1), -sin(#1), 0;
    sin(#1),  cos(#1), 0;
          0,        0, 1 }

\expandafter\matset\expandafter\transformMatrixA \expandafter
 {\GetRotationMatrix {3.141592653}}

 \begin{equation}
   \mattypeset \transformMatrixA
 \end{equation}
```

Here embedded at the end of the [code of Bruno Le Floch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112683/4686)

```
% Programming-level functions: \fpm_new:N, \fpm_set:Nn, \fpm_gset:Nn,
% \fpm_add:NNN, \fpm_sub:NNN, \fp_neg:NN, \fp_transpose:NN, \fp_mul:NNN.
%
% Expandable programming-level functions: \fpm_lines:N, \fpm_columns:N,
% \fpm_get:Nnn.
%
% Document-level functions: \matnew, \matset, \matgset, \matadd,
% \matsub, \matmul, \mattypeset.
%
\RequirePackage{expl3}
{
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  %
  % Programming-level code, for adding, multiplying, matrices.  A matrix
  % of size |MxN| is stored as a token list of the form
  %
  % \s__fpm { M } { N } { {a11} ... {a1N} } ... { {aM1} ... {aMN} } ;
  %
  % where |\s__fpm| is a marker used to recognize matrices, |M| and |N|
  % are non-negative integers, and |aij| are floating point numbers.
  %
  % (1) Variables.
  %
  \cs_new_eq:NN \s__fpm \scan_stop: % A marker.
  \tl_const:Nn \c_empty_fpm { \s__fpm { 0 } { 0 } ; }
  \cs_new_eq:NN \l__fpm_tmpa_fpm \c_empty_fpm
  \seq_new:N \l__fpm_lines_seq
  \int_new:N \l__fpm_lines_A_int
  \int_new:N \l__fpm_lines_B_int
  \int_new:N \l__fpm_columns_A_int
  \int_new:N \l__fpm_columns_B_int
  \tl_new:N \l__fpm_matrix_A_tl
  \tl_new:N \l__fpm_matrix_B_tl
  \tl_new:N \l__fpm_matrix_C_tl
  \seq_new:N \l__fpm_matrix_A_seq
  \seq_new:N \l__fpm_matrix_B_seq
  \seq_new:N \l__fpm_one_line_A_seq
  \seq_new:N \l__fpm_one_line_B_seq
  \tl_new:N \l__fpm_one_line_A_tl
  \int_new:N \l__fpm_tmpa_int
  %
  % (2) Variants and generic helpers.
  %
  %
  % (3) Storing matrices.
  %
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \fpm_new:N #1
    { \cs_new_eq:NN #1 \c_empty_fpm }
  \cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \fpm_set:Nn
    { \__fpm_set:NNn \tl_set:Nx }
  \cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \fpm_gset:Nn
    { \__fpm_set:NNn \tl_gset:Nx }
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \__fpm_set:NNn #1#2#3
    {
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fpm_lines_seq { ; } {#3}
      \seq_set_filter:NNn \l__fpm_lines_seq \l__fpm_lines_seq
        { ! \tl_if_empty_p:n {##1} }
      %
      % Now all lines are non-empty.
      %
      \tl_clear:N \l__fpm_matrix_A_tl
      \int_zero:N \l__fpm_lines_A_int
      \int_zero:N \l__fpm_columns_A_int
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__fpm_lines_seq
        {
          \int_incr:N \l__fpm_lines_A_int
          \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__fpm_one_line_A_seq {##1}
          \int_set:Nn \l__fpm_tmpa_int { \seq_count:N \l__fpm_one_line_A_seq }
          \int_compare:nNnT \l__fpm_columns_A_int = \c_zero
            { \int_set_eq:NN \l__fpm_columns_A_int \l__fpm_tmpa_int }
          \int_compare:nNnF \l__fpm_tmpa_int = \l__fpm_columns_A_int
            { \seq_map_break:n { \msg_error:nn { fpm } { invalid-size } } }
          \tl_put_right:Nx \l__fpm_matrix_A_tl
            { { \seq_map_function:NN \l__fpm_one_line_A_seq \__fpm_set_aux:n } }
        }
      #1 #2
        {
          \s__fpm
          { \int_use:N \l__fpm_lines_A_int }
          { \int_use:N \l__fpm_columns_A_int }
          \l__fpm_matrix_A_tl
          ;
        }
    }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_set_aux:n #1 { { \fp_to_tl:n {#1} } }
  %
  % (4) Extracting the size of a matrix, and its contents.
  % |#1| is the matrix, |#2|, |#3| integer variables receiving the
  % number of lines and of columns, and |#4| a token list receiving the
  % contents of the matrix.
  %
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \__fpm_get_parts:NNNN #1#2#3#4
    { \exp_after:wN \__fpm_get_parts:NnnwNNN #1 #2 #3 #4 }
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \__fpm_get_parts:NnnwNNN \s__fpm #1#2#3 ; #4#5#6
    {
      \int_set:Nn #4 {#1}
      \int_set:Nn #5 {#2}
      \tl_set:Nn #6 {#3}
    }
  %
  % (5) Some expandable functions: getting one entry, getting the size.
  %
  \cs_new:Npn \fpm_lines:N #1
    { \exp_after:wN \__fpm_lines:NnnwN #1 \use_i:nn }
  \cs_new:Npn \fpm_columns:N #1
    { \exp_after:wN \__fpm_lines:NnnwN #1 \use_ii:nn }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_lines:NnnwN \s__fpm #1#2#3 ; #4 { #4 {#1} {#2} }
  \cs_new:Npn \fpm_get:Nnn #1#2#3
    { \exp_after:wN \__fpm_get:Nnnwnn #1 #2 #3 }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_get:Nnnwnn \s__fpm #1#2#3 ; #4#5
    { \exp_args:Nf \tl_item:nn { \tl_item:nn {#3} {#4} } {#5} }
  %
  % (6) Summing matrices
  %
  \cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \fpm_add:NNN { \__fpm_add:NNNN + }
  \cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \fpm_sub:NNN { \__fpm_add:NNNN - }
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \__fpm_add:NNNN #1#2#3#4
    {
      \tl_set:Nn \l__fpm_sign_tl {#1}
      \__fpm_get_parts:NNNN #3
        \l__fpm_lines_A_int \l__fpm_columns_A_int \l__fpm_matrix_A_tl
      \__fpm_get_parts:NNNN #4
        \l__fpm_lines_B_int \l__fpm_columns_B_int \l__fpm_matrix_B_tl
      \int_compare:nNnTF \l__fpm_lines_A_int = \l__fpm_lines_B_int
        {
          \int_compare:nNnTF \l__fpm_columns_A_int = \l__fpm_columns_B_int
            { \__fpm_add:N #2 }
            { \msg_error:nn { fpm } { invalid-size } }
        }
        { \msg_error:nn { fpm } { invalid-size } }
    }
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \__fpm_add:N #1
    {
      \seq_set_split:NnV \l__fpm_matrix_A_seq { } \l__fpm_matrix_A_tl
      \seq_set_split:NnV \l__fpm_matrix_B_seq { } \l__fpm_matrix_B_tl
      \tl_clear:N \l__fpm_matrix_C_tl
      \seq_mapthread_function:NNN
        \l__fpm_matrix_A_seq
        \l__fpm_matrix_B_seq
        \__fpm_add_lines:nn
      \tl_set:Nx #1
        {
          \s__fpm
          { \int_use:N \l__fpm_lines_A_int }
          { \int_use:N \l__fpm_columns_A_int }
          \l__fpm_matrix_C_tl
          ;
        }
    }
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \__fpm_add_lines:nn #1#2
    {
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fpm_one_line_A_seq { } {#1}
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fpm_one_line_B_seq { } {#2}
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__fpm_matrix_C_tl
        {
          {
            \seq_mapthread_function:NNN
              \l__fpm_one_line_A_seq
              \l__fpm_one_line_B_seq
              \__fpm_add_entries:nn
          }
        }
    }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_add_entries:nn #1#2
    { { \fp_to_tl:n { #1 \l__fpm_sign_tl #2 } } }
  %
  % (7) Negating all entries.
  %
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \fpm_neg:NN #1#2
    { \tl_set:Nx #1 { \exp_after:wN \__fpm_neg:Nnnw #2 } }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_neg:Nnnw \s__fpm #1#2#3 ;
    { \s__fpm {#1} {#2} \tl_map_function:nN {#3} \__fpm_neg_aux:n ; }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_neg_aux:n #1
    { { \tl_map_function:nN {#1} \__fpm_neg_auxii:n } }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_neg_auxii:n #1
    { { \fp_to_tl:n { - #1 } } }
  %
  % (8) Transposing a matrix.
  %
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \fpm_transpose:NN #1#2
    {
      \__fpm_get_parts:NNNN #2
        \l__fpm_lines_A_int \l__fpm_columns_A_int \l__fpm_matrix_A_tl
      \seq_set_split:NnV \l__fpm_matrix_A_seq { } \l__fpm_matrix_A_tl
      \tl_clear:N \l__fpm_matrix_B_tl
      \prg_replicate:nn { \l__fpm_columns_A_int }
        {
          \tl_put_right:Nx \l__fpm_matrix_B_tl
            { { \seq_map_function:NN \l__fpm_matrix_A_seq \__fpm_wrap_head:n } }
          \seq_set_map:NNn \l__fpm_matrix_A_seq \l__fpm_matrix_A_seq
            { \tl_tail:n {##1} }
        }
      \tl_set:Nx #1
        {
          \s__fpm
          { \int_use:N \l__fpm_columns_A_int }
          { \int_use:N \l__fpm_lines_A_int }
          \l__fpm_matrix_B_tl
          ;
        }
    }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_wrap_head:n #1 { { \tl_head:n {#1} } }
  %
  % (9) Multiplying matrices.
  %
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \fpm_mul:NNN #1#2#3
    {
      \int_compare:nNnTF { \fpm_columns:N #2 } = { \fpm_lines:N #3 }
        {
          \fpm_transpose:NN \l__fpm_tmpa_fpm #3
          \__fpm_get_parts:NNNN #2
            \l__fpm_lines_A_int \l__fpm_columns_A_int \l__fpm_matrix_A_tl
          \__fpm_get_parts:NNNN #3
            \l__fpm_lines_B_int \l__fpm_columns_B_int \l__fpm_matrix_B_tl
          \tl_set:Nx #1
            {
              \s__fpm
              { \int_use:N \l__fpm_lines_A_int }
              { \int_use:N \l__fpm_columns_B_int }
              \tl_map_function:NN \l__fpm_matrix_A_tl \__fpm_mul_line:n
              ;
            }
        }
        { \msg_error:nn { fpm } { invalid-size } }
    }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_mul_line:n #1
    { { \exp_after:wN \__fpm_mul_line:Nnnwn \l__fpm_tmpa_fpm {#1} } }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_mul_line:Nnnwn \s__fpm #1#2#3 ; #4
    { \__fpm_mul_line:nn {#4} #3 \q_recursion_tail \q_recursion_stop }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_mul_line:nn #1#2
    {
      \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#2}
      {
        \fp_to_tl:n
          {
            \__fpm_mul_one:nwn #1 \use_none_delimit_by_q_stop:w
              \q_mark #2 \q_nil \q_stop
            0
          }
      }
      \__fpm_mul_line:nn {#1}
    }
  \cs_new:Npn \__fpm_mul_one:nwn #1#2 \q_mark #3
    { #1 * #3 + \__fpm_mul_one:nwn #2 \q_mark }
  %
  %
  % Messages.
  %
  \msg_new:nnn { fpm } { invalid-size }
    { Sizes~of~matrices~or~lines~don't~match. }
}
\RequirePackage{amsmath, siunitx}
{
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  %
  % Turning matrices into arrays for display.
  %
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \fpm_to_array:N #1
    {
      \begin{pmatrix}
        \exp_after:wN \__fpm_to_array:Nnnw #1
      \end{pmatrix}
    }
  \cs_new_eq:NN \__fpm_newline: ? % Dummy def.
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \__fpm_to_array:Nnnw \s__fpm #1#2#3 ;
    {
      \cs_gset_nopar:Npn \__fpm_newline:
        { \cs_gset_nopar:Npn \__fpm_newline: { \\ } }
      \tl_map_inline:nn {#3}
        {
          \__fpm_newline:
          \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fpm_one_line_A_seq { } {##1}
          \seq_set_map:NNn \l__fpm_one_line_A_seq \l__fpm_one_line_A_seq
            { \__fpm_to_array_entry:n {####1} }
          \seq_use:Nnnn \l__fpm_one_line_A_seq { & } { & } { & }
        }
    }
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \__fpm_to_array_entry:n #1
    {
      \str_case:nnn {#1}
        {
          { nan } { \text{nan} }
          { inf } { \infty }
          { -inf } { -\infty }
        }
        { \num{#1} }
    }
}

\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%
% Document-level functions.
%
\NewDocumentCommand { \matnew } { m } { \fpm_new:N #1 }
\NewDocumentCommand { \matset } { mm } { \fpm_set:Nn #1 {#2} }
\NewDocumentCommand { \matgset } { mm } { \fpm_gset:Nn #1 {#2} }
\NewDocumentCommand { \matadd } { mmm } { \fpm_add:NNN #1 #2 #3 }
\NewDocumentCommand { \matsub } { mmm } { \fpm_sub:NNN #1 #2 #3 }
\NewDocumentCommand { \matneg } { mm } { \fpm_neg:NN #1 #2 }
\NewDocumentCommand { \mattranspose } { mm } { \fpm_transpose:NN #1 #2 }
\NewDocumentCommand { \matmul } { mmm } { \fpm_mul:NNN #1 #2 #3 }
\NewDocumentCommand { \mattypeset } { m }
  { \fpm_to_array:N #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \matnew \X
  \matnew \Y
  \matnew \Z
  \matset \X { 1 , 2 + 3 ; 4 , 3.4e22 }
  \matset \Y { 3 , 4 ; -5 , 6 }
  \begin{align}
    \matadd \Z \X \Y
    \mattypeset \Z & = \mattypeset \X + \mattypeset \Y \\
    \matsub \Z \X \Y
    \mattypeset \Z & = \mattypeset \X - \mattypeset \Y \\
    \matmul \Z \X \Y
    \mattypeset \Z & = \mattypeset \X \times \mattypeset \Y \\
    \matmul \Z \Y \X
    \mattypeset \Z & = \mattypeset \Y \times \mattypeset \X
  \end{align}
\def\GetRotationMatrix #1{%
    cos(#1), -sin(#1), 0;
    sin(#1),  cos(#1), 0;
          0,        0, 1 }

\expandafter\matset\expandafter\transformMatrixA \expandafter
 {\GetRotationMatrix {3.141592653}}

 \begin{equation}
   \mattypeset \transformMatrixA
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The first four equations are the ones from the original code

> [image: matrices]

Comment: Why don't you make it a complete document please?

Comment: @jfbu: That fixes the problem (+1).  I couldn't parse what all the "\expandafter"s do.  I read the manual page, but this is a lot more complicated.  If you explain it, I'll accept as answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess one option would be to change the definition of `\matset` to `\NewDocumentCommand { \matset } { mm } { \fpm_set:Nx #1 {#2} }` and define the variant `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fpm_set:Nn { Nx }`.  The `\fpm_set:Nx` function then performs `\edef` expansion on `#2`, rather than a single step of expansion as the `\expandafter` that jfbu suggests.  I am not sure what is the best approach here (or rather, I know that the best approach would require some changes to `l3fp`, which I do not yet have time to code).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch in `xint` I use `\romannumeral-\`0` systematically to expand the arguments. I can not do `\edef` as the `xint` macros want to be completely expandable.