# TikZ Dimension too large Matrix Transform

Tags: calculations, dimensions

I'm working on some matrix transformation code, and I keep getting

```
! Dimension too large.
```

I traced it down to the following simple example.  The problem does not occur when `2e-17` is replaced with `0`.

```
\edef\MATRIXaa{1}
\edef\MATRIXba{2e-17}
\edef\MATRIXbb{1}
\edef\MATRIXab{0}
\tikzset{#1/.estyle={
    cm={
        \MATRIXaa,\MATRIXba, %Note this call takes transpose
        \MATRIXab,\MATRIXbb,
        (0,0)
    }
}}
```

Comment: `2e-17` is too small for both TeX's fixed-point number and PGF's floating-point math engine (I think).

Comment: Odd that it says it's too large then.  Anyway, given that IRL the numbers will be generated programmatically, how can it be fixed robustly?

Comment: @jfbu: I have just tried xintfrac.  It looks promising, but when I try e.g.       `\xintRound{4}{\MATRIXbb}` with the real values, it gives `! Missing = inserted for \ifnum`.  However, in both the hardcoded value and actual case, `\show\MATRIXbb` report the same (`2e-17` or similar)?

Comment: `\fp_to_tl:n { round(\MATRIXba, 4) }` (used within `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff`) from the `expl3` package should round to the closest multiple of 10^{-4}.

Comment: Added `\ExplSyntaxOn\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand { \round } { m} { \fp_to_tl:n { round(#1, 4) } } \ExplSyntaxOff` and it worked.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is not reproducible with your example. However, there are certain tasks that require a matrix inversion behind the scenes at the engine level and that can trip up the math overflow.

```
\def\MATRIXaa{1}
\def\MATRIXba{2e-17}
\def\MATRIXbb{1}
\def\MATRIXab{0}
\tikzset{my cm/.style={cm/.expanded={\MATRIXaa,\MATRIXba,\MATRIXab,\MATRIXbb,(0,0)}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,red] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (10,10);
\begin{scope}[my cm]
\draw[style=help lines,white,] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (10,10);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This code survives without any errors with TikZ v3.0