# Row to column table

Tags: tables, longtable

Is there any way to transpose table? I mean row to column and column to row?

Here is the code.

```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{article} % <-- remove12pt, again too big for your table.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{comment}
\oddsidemargin-16mm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand{\specificthanks}[1]{\@fnsymbol{#1}}% Inserts a specific \thanks symbol
%\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.0in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry} %<---- your table is larger then your original setting by geometry above
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables for horizontal lines
\newcommand{\piRsquare}{\pi r^2}
\begin{document}
\baselineskip=22pt
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabularx}{1.3\textwidth}{|l|*{10}{X|}}\hline
& Low & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & High \\ \hline
Fall & Consumer Staples 15.83\% & Healthcare 17.70\% & Utilities 19.48\% & Industrials 23.36\% & Consumer Discretionary 24.04\% & Energy 24.87\% & Telecom 25.50\% & Materials 26.92\% & Financials 28.33\% &Information Technology 34.91\% \\ \hline
2000 & Utilities 14.50\% & Consumer Staples 15.92\%  & 200 & & & & & & &\\\hline 
2001& Consumer Staples 16.70\% & Utilities 16.81\% & & & & & & & & \\\hline
2002& Consumer Staples 21.20\% & Utilities 22.49\% & & & & & & & & \\\hline
2031& Consumer Staples 17.49\% & Utilities 18.67\% & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
2004& Consumer Staples 10.04\% & Utilities 10.70\% & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
2005& Consumer Staples 8.73\% & Financials 10.25\% & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
2006& Consumer Staples 9.66\% & Healthcare 11.46\% & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
2007& Healthcare 12.58\% & Consumer Staples 12.77\% & & & & & & & & \\\hline
2008& Consumer Staples 28.83\% & Healthcare 28.84\% & & & & & & & & \\\hline
2009& Healthcare 16.10\% & Consumer Staples 16.64\% & & & & & & & & \\\hline
2010& Healthcare 13.59\% & Consumer Staples 14.53\% & & & & & & & & \\\hline
2011& Consumer Staples 14.21\% & Healthcare 15.89\% & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
2012& Consumer Staples 11.12\% & Healthcare 11.28\% & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Distantly related: [Perform matrix operations (addition, product, transpose, etc.) in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112599/5764)

Comment: Have you had a look at this?

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75793/tabular-input-by-columns-i-e-transpose-a-table

Comment: Is it complicated? I mean, is there any package that will convert the row to column? 

`\begin{the new package}?
my code 
\end{the new package}`

Comment: It is complicated yes:-) the question does appear to be a duplicate of the one Mil referenced, unless there is a special feature of your table that you want to highlight?

Comment: Actually I do not want to change anything of my table  :'( .  I just need to  interchange the row column. I mean transposing.