# Sum of (example: 0+1+2+3 = 6 , 0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7 = 28 and so on)

Tags: math-mode, calculations

Can anyone help please? I need to know how to make the sum of value S(n) = 0+1+2+3+4...+(n-1)+n (example: 0+1+2+3 = 6 , 0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7 = 28 and so on) on Latex

Comment: Your question is very unclear, do you mean you want to typeset that ( `$0+1+2+3=6$` would work) or you want latex do do the calculation or...?

Comment: I want, when the user enter a value n, the program gives the sum like 0+1+2+3=6. For example, if the user enter 5,the program 0+1+2+3+4+5 = 15.

Comment: if the user enters 8, program should calculate 0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8 = 36 and return 36 on the pdf

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112599/perform-matrix-operations-addition-product-transpose-etc-in-latex

Comment: do you know how to work on LISP? because I did on LISP already and now I need to do the same thing on LateX

Comment: `\sum\limits^{3}_{k=0} k` would be the shortest ;-) Perhaps there is even some version using Einstein's convention ;-)

Comment: `n*(n+1)/2` is the nth triangular number. The nth triangular number is your `S(n)`. (this is perhaps most useful if you only need to show the end result, not the `0+1+2+...` part)

Answer (score 21):

The difficult task is generating the terms of the sequence, not computing the sum, of course; I present a macro that prints all the terms or just the sum. You can define a different starting point and another difference (defaults 0 and 1).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\arithmeticsequence}{sO{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn {rudstep/arseq} { #2 }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \rudstep_arseq_sum:n { #3 } }
   { \rudstep_arseq_full:n { #3 } }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { rudstep/arseq }
 {
  diff  .int_set:N = \l_rudstep_diff_int,
  start .int_set:N = \l_rudstep_start_int,
  diff  .initial:n = 1,
  start .initial:n = 0,
 }
\seq_new:N \l_rudstep_terms_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \rudstep_arseq_full:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_rudstep_terms_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn
   { \l_rudstep_start_int } % start
   { \l_rudstep_diff_int }  % step
   { \l_rudstep_start_int + #1*\l_rudstep_diff_int }  % end
   { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_rudstep_terms_seq { ##1 } }
  $\seq_use:Nn \l_rudstep_terms_seq { + } = \rudstep_arseq_sum:n { #1 }$
 }
\cs_new:Npn \rudstep_arseq_sum:n #1
 {
  \int_eval:n { (#1+1)*(2*\l_rudstep_start_int+#1*\l_rudstep_diff_int)/2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Just the sum of five terms after 0: \arithmeticsequence*{5}

The whole sequence: \arithmeticsequence{3}

Or: \arithmeticsequence{4}

Start from 1: \arithmeticsequence[start=1]{3}

\bigskip

A big example: 
\arithmeticsequence[start=81297,diff=198]{180}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if you know how to do it in Lisp, then here's the way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lisp-on-tex}

\begin{document}

\lispinterp{
  (\define \intsum
    (\lambda (\n)
      (\lispif (\= \n :0 ) :0
        (\+ (\intsum (\- \n :1)) \n))))}

\lispinterp{(\texprint(\intsum:100))}

\end{document}
```

that prints, as is well known,

> 5050

Note: shamelessly adapted from the documentation of `lisp-on-tex`.

The e-TeX version of the same idea, using recursion, can be

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Sn}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr #1
    \ifnum\numexpr#1-1>0
      +\expandafter\Sn\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1-1}
    \fi
  \relax
}

\begin{document}

\Sn{10}

\Sn{100}

\end{document}
```

Note that this is fully expandable. The macro `\Sn` starts from the argument and if it's bigger than 1 asks to expand `\Sn` with the argument decreased by 1. One might start also from 0, but I'll leave it as an exercise to the interested reader.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\foo[1]{\the\numexpr((#1)*(#1+1))/2\relax}

% or if you want to print the terms
\newcommand\foob[1]{$\fooc{#1}{0}=\foo{#1}$}
\newcommand\fooc[2]{\the\numexpr#2\relax\ifnum#1=#2\relax\else+\fooc{#1}{\numexpr#2+1\relax}\fi}

\begin{document}

\foo{8} and \foo{5}

\foob{8} and \foob{5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much. it works. how to do it for Fibonacci?

Comment: @rudstep loads of solutions to that already: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fibonacci

Comment: can you please please explain me the codes you gave me for the SUM of value n.

Comment: @rudstep \numexpr is an (e-)tex primitive to do numerical calculations, and (n)(n+1)/2 is the well known formula for the sum of the integers up to n

Comment: Mister David Carliste thank you so much for your help. This help me a lot. but i don't understand the fibonacci on the link you sent me.

Comment: @rudstep The link does a search of the site and shows up previous questions about Fibonacci-related problems. Probably one or other of them will be helpful.

Comment: of course this provides the correct numerical answer, but if it's also required to print the complete sequence that sums to the result, then more is necessary.  (i could accuse you of being lazy if i didn't know better.  devious, definitely; lazy, no.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes the question wasn't clear on that (a bit more would be necessary, but not necessarily a long biographical treatise on Gauss:-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton see update

Answer (score 6):

Using Lua is probably a huge overkill in this situation, but it shows off how one can easily integrate Lua in LaTeX.

The code might also be easier to grasp for programmers who are beginners in LaTeX ;)

[image: Screenshot of the LaTeX script below]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{luacode}

% The code won't work as-is if you move it into \directlua{}.
% If you do so, be sure to replace "~" (in i ~= startInt) by \string~
\begin{luacode}
    function calcSum(startInt, endInt)
        local sum = 0
        for i=startInt, endInt do
            sum = sum + i
        end
        return sum
    end

    function writeSum(startInt, endInt)
        local sum = 0
        local tex = ""
        for i=startInt, endInt do
            if i ~= startInt then
                tex = tex .. " + "
            end
            sum = sum + i
            tex = tex .. i
        end
        tex = tex .. " = " .. sum
        return tex
    end
\end{luacode}

\def\calcSum#1#2{\directlua{
    tex.print(calcSum(tonumber(#1), tonumber(#2)))
}}
\def\writeSum#1#2{\directlua{
    tex.print(writeSum(tonumber(#1), tonumber(#2)))
}}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    The sum of the numbers \(0, 1, 2, \ldots, 28\) is \(\calcSum{0}{28}\).\\
    Another sum: \(\writeSum{100}{103}\).
\end{document}
```

Comment: May be `\string~` would work? Remember that everything is expanded (IIRC) before passing to Lua.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks, that did the trick! That's also one of the reasons that one should use external *.lua* files, I guess.

Comment: Or, at least, something more “prepared” than `\directlua`. I think `luacode` package offers some advances. In ConTeXt they have an environment where `\n`, `\t`, `~`, etc. needn't to be escaped since it's defined to work (I think that's what `luacode` does in LaTeX).

Comment: @Manuel LuaLaTeX says that `the environment luacode* [is] undefined`. I'll investigate tomorrow.

Comment: With `luacode` package, you have `\luaexec`, `luacode` environment, and `luacode*` environment.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks for your help! I updated the code again.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short `expl3` approach using `\int_step_inline:nnnn`. This carries out the explicit sum and doesn't rely on Gauss' reduction. So this is for illustration purposes only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_to_arabic:n { V }

\cs_new:Npn \rudstep_sum:n #1
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \int_add:Nn \l_tmpa_int { ##1 }
   }
  \int_to_arabic:V \l_tmpa_int
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \calcsum {m}
 {
  \rudstep_sum:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\calcsum{8}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, the child Gauss knew better. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

Using my package `calculator`, you can perform arithmetic calculations comfortably. This code solves your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calculator}

  \newcounter{n}
  \newcommand{\sumZeroToN}[2]{%
      \COPY{0}{#2}
      \whiledo{\not{\value{n}>#1}}{%
          \ADD{#2}{\value{n}}{#2}\stepcounter{n}}}

\begin{document}
    \sumZeroToN{100}{\sol}
    \[
         \sum_{n=0}^{100} n = \sol      
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: sum 1 to n]

Comment: That's cool, but it would be nice to see a solution [without `ifthen`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866) and which can calculate more than `\sumZeroToN{181}{\sol}`. If you have time, you could try that. It would also be nice to set the power just once. `\sum_{n=0}^{\power}`.

Answer (score 2):

An expandable solution using the package [bnumexpr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bnumexpr) for computations and `\xintiloop` for expandably looping with an index.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bnumexpr}% minimally extends \numexpr to big integers (new on CTAN
                     % as of 2014/09/22) 

% for \xintiloop: (for fun)
\usepackage{xinttools}% automatically loaded by xint, which is loaded by
                      % bnumexpr, but in the future bnumexpr will only load a
                      % smaller part of xint, and xint itself will not load
                      % xinttools anymore.

\newcommand{\ArithmeticSequenceAndItsSum}[3]{% 
  % #1= initial term, A
  % #2= common difference, d
  % #3= number of terms, N
  % sum is A+(A+d)+...+(A+(N-1)d)=N*A+d*N(N-1)/2 
  % (cf. Gauss Werke, Kindergarten Abteilung)
  %
  #1% assume N at least one and that #1 does not need to be evaluated
  \xintiloop [1+1]
  \unless\ifnum#3=\xintiloopindex
  +\thebnumexpr#1+\xintiloopindex*#2\relax
  \repeat
  =\thebnumexpr #3*#1+#2*#3*(#3-1)/2\relax
}

\begin{document}

$\ArithmeticSequenceAndItsSum {0}{1}{10}$

$\ArithmeticSequenceAndItsSum {1}{2}{10}$

\noindent $\ArithmeticSequenceAndItsSum {111111111}{111111111}{100}$

And now go see the log for some bigger integers!!

\message{\ArithmeticSequenceAndItsSum {123456789}{987654321}{1000}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: arithmetic sum]