# What does \xint_bye do?

Tags: xint

According to the xint packages source code, the definition of `\xint_bye` is

`\long\def\xint_bye #1\xint_bye {}%`.

Somehow it invokes itself, but I do not understand it.
What does `\xint_bye` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That definition doesn't mean that `\xint_bye` calls itself. The definition is of a macro with a *delimited argument*. According to it, `\xint_bye` must be followed by (almost<sup>1</sup>) arbitrary tokens and by `\xint_bye` at the same brace level. Everything up to and including that token is then discarded, because the replacement text is empty.

Actually, `\xint_bye` is mostly used as a “sentinel” for other delimited argument macros. I believe that the definition is done for corner cases when `\xint_bye` gets to be expanded (usually it's discarded, being an argument delimiter).

---

<sup>1</sup> *Almost*, because *outer* tokens cannot ever appear in arguments. Any other token can, including `\par`, because of the prefix `\long`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please add an explicit (code) use? or where can I learn how/when to use it?

Comment: @Chilote You don't use it. It's an internal token of the `xint` bundle.

Comment: I am trying to understand the code of the section ROW REDUCTION (INITIAL) ANSWER of this post where \xint_bye is explicitly used in lines 48, 51, etc: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360116/81269

Comment: @Chilote That's by the author of `xint`, who left this site. Clever code, poor documentation, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Chilote That answer mostly uses plain TeX, so you can read the books to learn the language; on the other hand it may be easier to learn Lua and reimplement the thing from scratch.