# Automatic matrix operations

Tags: matrices

I'm curious whether there is a package that could apply Gauss method for automatically step by step reduce rows in matrices, or find an inverse of one?

Something like `\polylongdiv` that receives two polynomials and divides them automatically.

Comment: How does this relate to (La)TeX? I assume you want it typeset, not just how to achieve an inverse given some matrix... right?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112599/perform-matrix-operations-addition-product-transpose-etc-in-latex