# Matrix operations on tikz math

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, pgfmath

Is possible I define a matrix A a vector x and compute the product b = A*x using tikzmath environment?
Many thanks.

Comment: LaTeX is markup language. It is intended for writing nice papers, reports and books. Calculation is not impossible, however this can be done with other programs far more easy and effective.

Comment: You could use LuaLaTeX for such a purpose, but you have to show your intended result, at least wrt typesetting.

Comment: See [perform matrix operations addition product transpose etc in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112599/perform-matrix-operations-addition-product-transpose-etc-in-latex/113167#113167).